# How do I assign a query result to a variable in Opencart/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, opencart

I'm having a problem trying to assign a single query result to a variable in Opencart. For example,

```
$variable = $this->db->query("SELECT value FROM mydb WHERE ID='example'");
```

From what I have read, $variable is now the result of the query in an associative array, if that is true, how can I get the string value from the associative array to be assigned to the variable? If I am wrong on anything I have said please correct me. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried this: http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=method_db_query

Comment: I have, but I don't quite understand how to return a string without making an array.

Comment: Do you want to get a single value from your query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT value FROM mydb WHERE ID='example'");

// Check if there are any rows returned from the query
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

    // Here you are getting array of your row.
    $row = $query->row;

    // Now here you are getting specific column value from our row into your variable.
    $variable = $row['yourcolumnname'];

   // Here we are echo our variable to test it.
    echo $variable;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried a version of this but forgot to add  $variable = $row['yourcolumnname']; that may be the problem. I will try this as soon as possible and let you know, Thank you!

Comment: It's ok and let me know if face any issues.

Comment: Your Wecome. You can accept my answer if it useful.